# How to set a php variable using a jQuery conditional test?

Tags: php, jquery, conditional-statements

I am trying to set a php variable using jQuery inside of a php file.

In my php file I want to run a jQuery script that tests if a condition is so and if so it sets a php var to one value or else it sets it to another value so I can use it later on in php.

I'm using this to try and set the size of my background image in wordpress based on window size. For now though, I'm just trying to echo the variable (`$bg_img_r`). Here is what I have:

```
<?php function bg_size() { ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            if ($(window).height()>720;  {
                <?php $bg_img_r = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bg_img_id, 'fullbg' ); ?>
            }
            if ($(window).height()<720; {
                <?php $bg_img_r = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bg_img_id, 'smallbg' ); ?>
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>

<?php
    echo $bg_img_r;
?>
```

When I do this I get an error that `$bg_img_r` is an undefined variable.

Comment: Php is server side code; jquery / JavaScript is client side. You can't mix the two like this because they don't run at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP happens entirely on the server side before Javascript even has a chance to execute. The server delivers the HTML to the client browser, then the browser runs the Javascript. Thus, it is not possible to use a javascript variable to affect PHP execution. You have to use a more complex system.

Probably the simplest way to solve your problem of conditionally setting the background image based on window height is to not set it at all on the server side, but instead include data- attributes that contain both possibilities and populate the correct one using javascript later. For example, you can include the data attributes like this:

```
<div id="content-with-background"
    data-fullbg-src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bg_img_id, 'fullbg' ); ?>"
    data-smallbg-src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bg_img_id, 'smallbg' ); ?>"
>
    <!-- html contents -->
</div>
```

Then use jquery to set the background appropriately:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var key = ($(window).height() > 720 ? 'fullbg-src' : 'smallbg-src');
    var $content = $('#content-with-background');
    $content.css('background-image', 'url(' + $content.data(key) + ')');
});
```

This javascript code would probably be in a `.js` file that include using `<script src="..."></script>`, but you can also embed it directly in `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>"` tags if you want.

This is just one possibility. There are other solutions too, such as using php to output javascript variables to store the backgrounds, and then conditionally set them, or use AJAX to retrieve the appropriate background url and use that (though I wouldn't recommend AJAX for this solution because it is an unnecessary extra server call, which can slow things down). You could even use css3 media queries and output a dynamically-created css file (this can be an elegant solution, but is not simple to set up). Some browsers even send http headers that include window size, and if your entire client bases uses such browsers, you can use those headers (but this solution requires specific conditions that don't usually exist for general-purpose web applications).

Comment: Ooo, I like this idea (including data attributes,for background and then set choose with jQuery.) Just taking a look at this, I think the browser is not actually going to load both backgrounds, right? The whole point of this exercise is to avoid loading a 1000+ pixel wide image for the background on a phone.

Comment: @JPollock, right, data- attributes are all but ignored by the browser, so it definitely won't load the images. So this solution will only load the image at the time it is assigned to the background-url (and it won't load the other one at all).

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this. This is what I get in the page source: `<div id="bg"
    data-fullbg-src="Array"
    data-smallbg-src="Array"
>` I put all of the code I used into a gist if you want to see https://gist.github.com/Shelob9/5551508 .

Comment: @JPollock, that means `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bg_img_id, 'fullbg' );` is returning an array instead of a string. You need to look up `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` in the documentation to figure out how it works. If you have trouble with that, post it as a new question on stackoverflow, because it is a separate problem. Once you get the strings, the method here will work.

Comment: You are correct. The solution was to do it like this: `"<?php $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bg_img_id, 'full' ); echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>"`. I have updated that gist accordingly for anyone who might be reading this.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it this way. php processes the file and sends the output to the remote computer. jquery is processed by the users computer so by the time the jquery is run, the server has gotten rid of this page.

it sounds like what you would want to do is a jquery ajax call back to the server to get the data you are looking for.